# Network: sending a video (in theory)

Tags: networking, video, theory

**Context**

- We have got un unsteady transmission channel. Some packets may be lost.
- Sending a single network packet in any direction (from A to B or from B to A) takes 3 seconds.
- We allow a signal delay of 5 seconds, no more. So we have a 5-second buffer. We can use those 5 seconds however we want.
- Currently we use only 80% of the transmission channel, so we have 1/4 more room to utilize.
- The quality of the video cannot be worsened.

**Problem**

We need to make the quality better. How to handle lost packets?

**Solution proposition**

A certain thing - we cannot use TCP in this case, because when TCP detects some problems, it requests retransmission of lost data. That would mean that a packet would arrive after 9 seconds, which is more than the limit.

Therefore we need to use UDP and handle those errors ourselves. How to do it then? How to make sure that not so many packets will be lost as currently, without retransmitting them?

Comment: Using UDP isn't going to magically fix the internet between your A and your B sites. Edge caching is the best way to deliver high-bandwidth content to far-away subscribers. Engage the services of a content delivery network. Seriously, they're very good at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a complicated solution, but by far the best option will be to add forward error correction (FEC). This is how images are transfered form space probes where the latency is measures in minutes or hours. Its also use by cell phones where delayed packets are bad for two way communication.

A not as good, but eaiser to implement option is to use UDT. This is a UDP with tcp like retranmission library, but allows you much more controll over the protocol.

Comment: YES! Forward error correction is the way to go. Thanks!!